# C# How limit child folders results with Directory.GetPath LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this function:

```
var dupeFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(fullPath => new
            {
                Name = Path.GetFileName(fullPath),
                FullPath = fullPath
            })
            .GroupBy(file => file.Name)
            .Where(fileGroup => fileGroup.Count() > 1);


        foreach (var dupeGroup in dupeFiles)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"DupeFiles.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(dupeGroup.Key);
            }

            foreach (var dupeFile in dupeGroup)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"DupeFiles.txt", true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine($"   {dupeFile.FullPath}");
                }

            }
        }
```

But im getting this result:

```
FILE.TXT
     ...\RootFolder\Folder1\Child1\AnotherChild\FILE.TXT
     ...\RootFolder\Folder1\Child2\AnotherChild\FILE.TXT
     ...\RootFolder\Folder1\Child3\FILE.TXT
     ...\RootFolder\Folder2\Child3\FILE.TXT
     ...\RootFolder\Folder2\Child2\AnotherChild\FILE.TXT
```

How limit the result for the same file path from folder1 and folder2 (or more, this same child level)? In that case, i just want the results:

```
FILE.TXT
   ...\RootFolder\Folder1\Child2\AnotherChild\FILE.TXT
   ...\RootFolder\Folder2\Child2\AnotherChild\FILE.TXT
```

Thank you!

Thank you all replys, but it stills don't helps. Maybe i can't tell you what exactly i need, so look those real pic:
[image: real case]

As you can see, the first file: NMS_REALITY_GCTECHNOLOGYTABLE.MBIN are repeated on 3 folders:

LessOverHeat10 ...
Reduced Launch Cost...
_BettterFreighter...

Thats all right, because as you can see, the same file was on (root) folders different.

But another other files, PLANTINTERACTION.ENTITY.MBIN, repeats on a lot of others folders, but inside the same folder:

_FASTER_FARMING_X50.

This part is wrong. I would lik to ignore (not list) all those files, because its for the same folder. I just would like to list, or mark them as conflicted, if its at the same path, but for different root folder.

Its better now? Thank you so much, sorry if can't explain right my needs.

Count on you, thanks!!!

Comment: Unrelated tip: consider putting the StreamWriter outside the foreach loops to avoid open/seek/close each time you write either of the types of line.

Answer (score -1):

Make a ParentPath attribute and group by that then select what you want from every parentDirectory by skipping all you don't want.

```
    var dupeFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(fullPath => new
    {
        Name = Path.GetFileName(fullPath),
        FullPath = fullPath,
        ParentPath = GetParentPath(fullPath)
        }).GroupBy(file => file.ParentPath)
        .Select(parentDirectory => parentDirectory
            .SkipWhile((childFile, index) => index != 1)
            .First()
         );


        StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(@"DupeFiles.txt", true);
        foreach(var aFile in dupeFiles.ToList())
           Console.WriteLine(aFile.FullPath);
```

...

```
    private string GetParentPath(string fullPath)
    {
        string [] strArr = fullPath.Split('\\');
        string parentPath = strArr[0] + '\\' + strArr[1] + '\\' + strArr[2] + '\\' + strArr[3] + '\\' + strArr[4] + '\\' + strArr[5];
        //Console.WriteLine("parentPath: " + parentPath);
        return parentPath;
    }
```

...

## Edited answer using double foreach and retaining IGrouping.Key

```
        string strPath = "C:\\Users\\Luke\\Desktop\\RootFolder";
        var dupeFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Select(fullPath => new
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileName(fullPath),
            FullPath = fullPath,
        }).GroupBy(file => GetParentPath(file.FullPath))
            .Select(parentDirectory => 
            parentDirectory.SkipWhile((childFile, index) => index != 1).First()
             ).GroupBy(file => file.Name, file => file.FullPath);



        foreach(var dupeGroup in dupeFiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("key is: " + dupeGroup.Key);
            foreach (var dupeFile in dupeGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dupeFile);
            }
        }

        /*example output
        
        key is: FILE.txt
        C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\RootFolder\Folder1\Child2\AnotherChild\FILE.txt
        C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\RootFolder\Folder2\Child2\AnotherChild\FILE.txt
        
        */
```

Comment: Thank you for help! I tested the code but it wont working =( The foreach aFile is returning only 1 option always. I changed the index inside .SkipWhile and the file that return is diferrent, but it only returns one file =( Tried my part of the code to foreach but it don't identity the .key param and dupeGroup =(
Any tip, please? Ty!!!!

Comment: The code is working for me. Your strPath should be the path to RootFolder for example string strPath = "C:\\Users\\Luke\\Desktop\\RootFolder";